# MongoDB Java Reactive Streams lifecycle Micronaut

Tags: java, mongodb, micronaut, mongodb-java, micronaut-data

I'm trying to implement the life cycle events of a **Java Reactive Streams MongoDB driver** with **Micronaut 3** application.

There is a requirement to perform **BeforeInsert()**, **AfterInsert()**, **BeforeUpdate()**, **AfterUpdate()**, **BeforeDelete()**, and **AfterDelete()** life cycle events with `com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient`.

The java driver documentation has examples of this: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/java/sync/current/fundamentals/monitoring/

1. Monitor Events
2. Command Events

However, this documentation doesn't show how to implement the life cycle events with **MongoDB Java Reactive Streams**. How do I implement the life cycle events with `com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient`?

```
@Singleton
public record Repository(MongoClient mongoClient, MongodbConfiguration mongodbConfiguration) implements IRepository {
    @Override
    public <T> MongoCollection<T> getCollection(String collectionName, Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
        return mongoClient
                .getDatabase(mongodbConfiguration.database())
                .getCollection(collectionName, typeParameterClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if the reactive streams monitoring docs might help: [MongoDB: reactive streams - monitoring](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver-reactive/reference/monitoring/).

Comment: As we know Micronaut uses the native java driver for mongo client. Trying to implement the CommandListener with 'io.micronaut.mongodb:micronaut-mongo-reactive:4.0.0'.
Seems like this doesn't contain the command listener as referring to https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver-reactive/reference/monitoring/

How can we use monitoring the mongo command with io.micronaut.mongodb:micronaut-mongo-reactive:4.0.0